# Call to a member function profile() on string error

Tags: string, laravel, function, member

I am trying to detach a field from a pivot table but I keep receiving the error 'call to member function on string' as an error. I am using the latest version of Laravel.

```php
public function removeProfile($child)
{
    $profile = Profile::find(1);
    $child->profiles()->detach($profile);

    return 'Success';
}
```

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
>   (E_ERROR) Call to a member function profile() on string

Comment: apparently, when you call the function removeProfile(), you're passing a string as parameter. Could you add the code from where the call to the function is made?

Answer (score 0):

in your model something tile this

```
return $this->belongsToMany('profie')->withPivot('user', 'profile');
```

and in your controller should be

```
$variable->profile()->where(some condition)->first()->pivot->your_entity
```